# How to use AIDL to pass by reference?

Tags: object, aidl

In android, I need one service running in the background to server multiple client applications. By using AIDL, I have exposed some simple interfaces to the clients successfully. But the return values and parameters are all primitive types. I also tried to use parcelable to pass object to clients, however, I found they are passed by VALUE.

Is there a way using AIDL or something else to pass object to the other application? Please help me.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to pass by Reference is to use Ashmem capabilities. You should create a shared memory region, create a binder that points on this region and then you can pass binder between applications. In this case binder is a kind of reference.